# Oracle SQL (Multiple stock items against one product id)

Tags: sql, oracle

Might be incredibly naive but it's troubling me nonetheless. As part of my coursework, I have to create a database system for imaginary customers purchasing an item that firstly needs to be made. One problem I'm having is allocating multiple stock items into the works orders table against one particular product ID. So for example, how would I get 4 legs and a table top which would come under two individual ID's (legs and table top) against the product id containing 'table'? I'm currently working with SQL plus.

[Image of my ERM is here for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CWP5.png)

Comment: Create a ProductStock table, with foreign key to Product & Stock, and an int column for the amount. So for example that 'table' product is represented with 2 row, one referring the 4 legs, the other for the single table top.

Comment: Thank you. How would that look in a table by the way? I'm trying to picture it.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/MOl8GPi.png), adjust the naming scheme as necessary

Comment: So you'd essentially have the same product_id on two rows with two different stock_id's if your referencing the table? I'm new to database design so bear with!

Comment: Yep. You really need to read some DB design 101 first.

Comment: ProductStock is a [junction table](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)